# Variable arguments with `\@ifnextchar`

Tags: macros

For consistent style of references, defined a Latex macro `\secn` that is able to handle multiple arguments.
If I provide a single argument `s1`, it should return `Section~\ref{sec:lbl}`.
If I provire multiple arguments `s1`, ..., `sn`, it should return `Sections~\ref{sec:s1}, ..., \ref{sec:s(n-1)} and \ref{sec:sn}`.

The following Latex macro almost accomplishes this, except that it does not generate the plural `Sections` in case of multiple arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\secn{\myref{Section}{Sections}{sec}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myref}[4]{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{#2}{#1}~\myreflist{#3}{#4}}
\newcommand{\myreflist}[2]{%
    \@ifnextchar\bgroup{\ref{#1:#2}\myreflisttail{#1}}{\ref{#1:#2}}}
\newcommand{\myreflisttail}[2]{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{, 
\ref{#1:#2}\myreflisttail{#1}}{ and \ref{#1:#2}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\secn{s1} \par
\secn{s1}{s2} \par
\secn{s1}{s2}{s3}

\section{test1}
\label{sec:s1}
\section{test2}
\label{sec:s2}
\section{test3}
\label{sec:s3}

\end{document}
```

The `\@ifnextchar` command in the definition of `\myref` always returns false.
Why is this the case? How can I get the plural form?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The cleveref package with the `\cref` command produces such output by default.

Comment: Macros with “variable number of arguments” are not the best way to go here.

Comment: A somewhat off-topic question: Am I the only one seeing the title incorrectly rendered? I see "Variable arguments with ∘ if ≠ xtchar".

Comment: @md2perpe: Probably.

Comment: @user21820. Today it looks good.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using a command with variable arguments I would suggest to use a command with a comma-separated list as argument. You can also use package [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), that already provides such a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[sort]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\cref{sec:s1} \par
\cref{sec:s1,sec:s2} \par
\cref{sec:s1,sec:s2,sec:s3}

\section{test1}
\label{sec:s1}
\section{test2}
\label{sec:s2}
\section{test3}
\label{sec:s3}

\end{document}
```

[image: with option sort]

Without option `sort` the default `sort&compress` is used, that would result in:

[image: with options sort&compress]

Answer (score 3):

The problem you get always the else clause is because you wrote `\newcommand{\myref}[4]{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{#2}{#1}~\myreflist{#3}{#4}}`, i.e. `\@ifnextchar\bgroup{#2}{#1}` always sees the `~` as next character. The if-next-char means the next char after it, not the macro it is part of!

You need to make sure that there is nothing after it, so I would suggest to move the remaining code into the clauses:

```
\newcommand{\myref}[4]{\@ifnextchar\bgroup{#2~\myreflist{#3}{#4}}{#1~\myreflist{#3}{#4}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd avoid “variable number of arguments”: a comma separated list is even simpler to type and to manage.

Here's an implementation with `xparse` and `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\generalref}{mmmm}
 {
  \kasper_generalref:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\secn}{m}
 {
  \generalref{Section}{Sections}{sec}{#1}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_kasper_generalref_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kasper_generalref:nnnn
 {
  % clear the sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l_kasper_generalref_seq
  % populate it
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #4 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_kasper_generalref_seq { \ref{#3:##1} }
   }
  % use first argument if less than two items
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l_kasper_generalref_seq < 2 } { #1 } { #2 }
  % no break between label and first reference
  \nobreakspace
  % issue the references (here ~ means a normal space)
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_kasper_generalref_seq
   { ~and\nobreakspace } % between two
   { ,~ } % between more than two
   { ~and\nobreakspace } % between last two
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\secn{s1} \par
\secn{s1,s2} \par
\secn{s1,s2,s3}

\section{test1}
\label{sec:s1}
\section{test2}
\label{sec:s2}
\section{test3}
\label{sec:s3}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `cleveref` is simpler, though (and more customizable}. The output is the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[nosort]{cleveref}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\gcref}{mm}
 {% #1 is the common prefix, #2 is the list of labels
  \kasper_gcref:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\secn}{m}
 {
  \gcref{sec}{#1}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_kasper_gcref_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \kasper_gcref:nn
 {
  % clear the sequence
  \seq_clear:N \l_kasper_gcref_seq
  % populate it
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_kasper_gcref_seq { #1:##1 }
   }
  \Cref {\seq_use:Nn \l_kasper_gcref_seq { , } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\secn{s1} \par
\secn{s1,s2} \par
\secn{s1,s2,s3}

\section{test1}
\label{sec:s1}
\section{test2}
\label{sec:s2}
\section{test3}
\label{sec:s3}

\end{document}
```